# Using array_agg from CTE with any

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to work with an old version of a database that doesn't have certain tables, so I am trying to emulate them with views.

I have to aggregate data from several tables in different ways. For some columns I have to check whether certain values are present, which I do with `value = any(array_agg)`. To not repeat `array_agg(table_name.column_name)` many times, I moved `array_agg`s into a CTE.

However when I try to use several of them with `any`, I receive the error `column "array_agg" must appear in the GROUP BY clause`. If I use only one of those columns, the query executes successfully.

The query looks approximately like this:

```
with cte as(
select
 a.id                   aid,
 array_agg(b.timestamp) timestamp,
 array_agg(c.kind)      kind
from      a
left join b on b.id = a.bid
left join c on c.id = b.cid
group by a.id
)
select
 aid,
 case when 
  null = any(timestamp)
 then 
  null
 else 
  min(timestamp)
 end as mincount,
 case when 'B' = any(kind) then 'B'
      when 'A' = any(kind) then 'A'
      when 'C' = any(kind) then 'C'
      when 'D' = any(kind) then 'B'
 end as kind
from cte
group by aid
```

I get the following errors:

```
the column "cte.timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
the column "cte.kind"      must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

If I remove one of the `any`s, errors disappear. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You are not rally using the arrays in the outer query anyway, so why not simply use `min(b.timestamp)` in the CTE and forget about using `array_agg()` completely?

Comment: I can't just use `min` because I have to return a null if there are any nulls.

Answer (score 0):

It seems rather strange to do this using arrays.  But you don't need the outer aggregation:

```
select aid,
       (select min(ts) from unnest(cte.timestamps) ts) as min_timestamp,
       (case when 'A' = any(kind) then 'A'
             when 'B' = any(kind) then 'A'
             when 'C' = any(kind) then 'B'
             when 'D' = any(kind) then 'B'
             else 'C'
        end) as kind
from cte;
```

EDIT:

If you need to return `NULL` if *any* values are `NULL`, then:

```
       (select ts from unnest(cte.timestamps) ts order by ts limit 1) as min_timestamp,
```

The `order by` will put `NULL` values first.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . The OP specifically says that the CTE is desired to emulate another table.  It is strange, though.

Comment: I can't just use `min` because I have to return a `null` if there are any nulls. But the query that I posted seems to not work properly, I seem to have broken it when I was censoring it.